# Don't recommend jobs with tags for which I've had no participation

Tags: discussion, jobs, android-app, android-app-feed

I've never answered or asked a php question so I'm not interested in php jobs.

More generally what are people's thoughts on filtering the android app's feed to only show job listings for tags I've participated in?

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combined with explicit "show me more like this" and "show me less like this" for all feed items are both planned for further down the line.